How to change the default file manager to Pantheon-files in Ubuntu LTS 22.04?
I want to change the the defaut file manager from Nautilus to Pantheon-files (which I already installed in Ubuntu LTS 22.04). I had a look at the following question:
https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/512/how-to-replace-file-manager-in-elementary-os
But the file /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop does not exist (although /usr/share/applications/nautilus-autorun-software.desktop exists but there is no OnlyShowIn option)
Is there a way to do it?

I Would suggest caution, Nautilus is configured in GUI of the Ubuntu, even more in 24.04 If you ever decided to upgrade.
What you are looking for is called org-gnome-Nautilus.desktop and it is in the same directory.
Copy it somewhere so that you have a backup just in case.
There is a possibility that you are following an answer that was made for earlier version of Ubuntu.
https://techviewleo.com/install-pantheon-desktop-environment-on-ubuntu/ has explained how to install on both 20.04 and 22.04.
There are also a lot of answered questions about Pantheon in this site, you may search them and may be some of them apply.

I would suggest searching more and also finding out how to uninstall Pantheon if the need arises.


Thanks for your answer @amar. There is indeed a org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop but there is still no OnlyShowIn option in it. What do you mean I should do to change Pantheon as my default file manager?

I installed nero not Pantheon, so I am not sure, it is possible that discussion was for earlier versions of Ubuntu and since then the file has changed alas name change, pls read this https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/vai8z2/ubuntu_2204_tried_pantheon_desktop/ and this https://techviewleo.com/install-pantheon-desktop-environment-on-ubuntu/ . It is best to do a through search if you want to change something major.

I would suggest you search more than those two I have posted to get a clear idea of how to install (and uninstall if necessary). There is a lot of answered questions here about Pantheon, some of them may apply.

I followed the link of techview and that actually worked! I already upvoted your answer. You can change the answer accordingly and I would be glad to accept it
